# Event Receivers Choosing lists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How Can I choose a lists in Event Receivers propeties. Please help. I Know i should set in XML   `<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">`, but how I should choose one from another ? **Please help me**

I want to puts one content to another but i don't know haw choose:

```
       public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {

       properties.AfterProperties["Numer Kontraktu/Oferty/Szansy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Numer Kontraktu/Oferty/Szansy"];
       properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik"];
       properties.AfterProperties["Dzień"] = properties.AfterProperties["Dzień Start"];

       base.ItemAdding(properties);

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Grzegorz Z,

I think now I get your question, do something like this:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   base.ItemAdding(properties);
   if (properties.List.Title == "ListName")
   {
      SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["AnotherListName"];
      SPListItem item = lstOtherList.GetItemById(2);

      item["Numer Kontraktu/Oferty/Szansy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Numer Kontraktu/Oferty/Szansy"];
      item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik"];
      item["Dzień"] = properties.AfterProperties["Dzień Start"];
   }
}
```

Is this something you are trying to do? Update another item in another list with the content of the item being added ?

Comment: Yes i think Yes, but here at `SPListItem item = lstOtherList.GetItemById(2);` I get null and **ArgumentException wos unhandled by user code**

Comment: It was just an example, replace 2 with the Id of the item you want to get.. GetItemById(ItemId); Also, here you can use SPQuery and write CAML to query the item you want from another list

Comment: I think I'm nere to get in tought to solution thanks You :)
`       if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
           {
               SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];
               SPListItem item = lstOtherList.AddItem();

               item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
               item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik"];
               item["Dzien"] = properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"];

               item.Update();
           }
           base.ItemAdding(properties);
       }` but same fields are don't come.

Comment: base.ItemAdding(properties); if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy") { SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"]; SPListItem item = lstOtherList.AddItem(); item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"]; item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik"]; item["Dzien"] = properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"]; item.Update(); }  }

Comment: call base.ItemAdding(properties); at the top... then add the new item in other list!

Comment: Jes but what is deference of putting   
base.ItemAdding(properties); on top or bottom. Can You describe me ?

Comment: Grzegorz, did that work? base.ItemAdding is actually the base class method, remember we are overriding the methods in Event Receivers, but they have some default implementations in base class.. So if you don't want to disturb its default functionality as in your case, we just called the base class method first!

Answer (score 1):

To bind a receiver to a specific list, You can also set List Url in Receivers tag as:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Tasks">
```

For this to work, your feature should have scope=web.

Check here for more details: http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/12/27/event-receivers-sharepoint-2010/